# MySql pivot table dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I've got the following tables in my database:

this is the table **km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values**
[image]

this is the table **km_kondomanager_millesimal_table**
[image]

The two tables are joined together by km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id and km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_id

I've managed to creat a pivot table using the followinf query:

```
SELECT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id = 9
                     THEN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value END) tabella_gruppo_A
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id = 10
                     THEN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value END) tabella_gruppo_B 
FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values 
WHERE km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_group_id = 15
GROUP BY km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id
```

and this is how it looks like:

[image]

My problem is that I need to take the table name from km_kondomanager_millesimal_table and use it as column, these columns are not always the same as you can see in the immage there are other stored in the database. The query I've created requires to specify km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id in the case and also to specify the column name in the example tabella_gruppo_A and tabella_gruppo_B. Can anyboby help me to achieve this? Also I need to convert the pit table to HTML table. Many thanks

Comment: What is your expected result? Also please  post the expected result as text rather than images with some sample columns instead of actual long named columns.

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai thanks for your answer, the result I’m aspecting is the same I get with my query but I need to obtain it dynamically

Comment: This dynamically builds and optionally executes a "pivot":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it sorted using mysql stored procedure and this is the code:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT

    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("MAX(IF(km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id='", km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id, "',km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value ,NULL)) AS '", km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name, "'"), "
"
      )INTO @answers
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id, km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values INNER JOIN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table
                 ON km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values . km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id = km_kondomanager_millesimal_table. km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_id WHERE km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_group_id = 13
    ) A;

    SET @query := 
      CONCAT(
        'SELECT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id, ', @answers, 
        ' FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values WHERE km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_group_id = 13 GROUP BY km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id'
      );

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;
    EXECUTE statement;
END
```